# How to override a file in wordpress with child theme?

Tags: wordpress

I am wanting to edit an existing file from a theme's existing files and place it in my child theme, so upon updating there is no issue with remaking the page.

I basically want to delete some code/functionality that the theme provides to speed up the site. So I'd rather not use a display: none; approach.

The file is located in: 
/inc/widgets/courses/tpl/file.php

How can I make this possible, simply copying the file into the child theme with the associated folders does not work. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

No you can't overwrite the file just copying the file and place it in the child theme. To overwrite the function you must check first for magic functions. Another way to overwrite a parent theme functionality in the child theme is Using Wordpress Hooks and filters.

Comment: I'm not quite wanting to replace a function though at least not that I can tell. There is no creation of a function in the file.

Comment: ok then another way is the where you are including this file, just change the path so path pick the file form your child directory.